# Create a PHP table with an if condition in it

Tags: php, if-statement, html-table, conditional-statements, variable-assignment

[Assignment description](https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/-NCl7a_GDE5c/U7ckAFBFuCI/AAAAAAAAAHs/vIEUdlwYDJA/w737-h553-no/2014-07-04)

I have an assignment and it requires to create a table with 2 dimensional array and the third column to report the grade according to grading system as it shows in the picture.

I made the code for table creation, but I am stuck with the conditioning for the grade column and how to apply it in the table.

Can someone please help me with this ?

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<?php
$a=array('0'=>array('Course','Mark','Grade'),
         '1'=>array('OS',90,''),
         '2'=>array('MIS',85,''),
         '3'=>array('WD',99,''),
         '4'=>array('OOP',67,''),
         '5'=>array('DS',70,''),
         '6'=>array('Prog',80,'')
         );
     echo"<table border='2px black solid'>";
     for($x=0;$x<7;$x++){
     echo"<tr>";
     for($y=0;$y<3;$y++){
     echo "<td>".$a[$x][$y].'</td>';
     }
     echo"</tr>";
     }
     echo"</table>";
     ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stackoverflow is not for answering assignment questions, but it seems like you have put your effort. You have to display grade  in the third column ie, when $y =2 (0,1,2). So you can do it like this.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<?php
$a=array('0'=>array('Course','Mark','Grade'),
         '1'=>array('OS',90,''),
         '2'=>array('MIS',85,''),
         '3'=>array('WD',99,''),
         '4'=>array('OOP',67,''),
         '5'=>array('DS',70,''),
         '6'=>array('Prog',80,'')
         );
     echo"<table border='2px black solid'>";
     for($x=0;$x<7;$x++){
     echo"<tr>";
     for($y=0;$y<3;$y++){
        if($y == 2)
        {
            //Your grade logic 
            $grade = logic($a[$x][1]); //You can define some function that takes marks and return grade
            echo "<td>".$grade.'</td>';
        }
        else
        {
             echo "<td>".$a[$x][$y].'</td>';
        }
     }
     echo"</tr>";
     }
     echo"</table>";
     ?>
</body>
</html>
```

**Edit**

```
   <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <?php
    $a=array('0'=>array('Course','Mark','Grade'),
             '1'=>array('OS',90,''),
             '2'=>array('MIS',85,''),
             '3'=>array('WD',99,''),
             '4'=>array('OOP',67,''),
             '5'=>array('DS',70,''),
             '6'=>array('Prog',80,'')
             );
         echo"<table border='2px black solid'>";
         for($x=0;$x<7;$x++){
         echo"<tr>";
         for($y=0;$y<3;$y++){
            if($y == 2)
            {
                //Your grade logic 
                $marks = $a[$x][1];
                if($marks > 90)
                {
                   $grade = 'A';
                }
                else if($marks > 80)
                {
                   $grade = 'B';
                }
                else if($marks > 70)
                {
                   $grade = 'C';
                }
                else if($marks > 60)
                {
                   $grade = 'D';
                } 
                else
                {
                   $grade = 'E';
                }
                echo "<td>".$grade.'</td>';
            }
            else
            {
                 echo "<td>".$a[$x][$y].'</td>';
            }
         }
         echo"</tr>";
         }
         echo"</table>";
         ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you Mr Abhishek , I did not know it is not allowed to help in assignments here. I really find it hard to understand the logic in multi array elements selection to assign for the condition.

Comment: Marked and really helpful , sorry for the trouble :)

Comment: use an switch it look alot nicer.

switch($marks){
case >90:
    //logic
    break;
case
>......

Answer (score 0):

[EXAMPLE HERE](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/befaa7298657d215a4629785773a2290dbb84716)

First define your grade logic function...

```
// Define your Grade Logic function
function getGrade($grade){
 if($grade>20 && $grade<40){return 'D';}
 if($grade>=40 && $grade<=60){return 'C';}
 if($grade>=61 && $grade<=80){return 'B';}
 if($grade>=81 && $grade<=100){return 'A';}
}
```

Then apply it in your loop...

```
// Start table
echo "<table border='2px black solid'>";

//Loop through your array
foreach($a as $k=>$v){

// If key is 0, means its the column row, echo headers
if($k==0){
  echo "<tr><td>".$a[$k][0]."</td><td>".$a[$k][1]."</td><td>".$a[$k][2]."</td></tr>";
} else {
// Else echo the table TD's
// Start table row
echo "<tr>";
// loop through the array of grades for each row
foreach($v as $key=>$val){

   echo "<td>";
   // If key is 1, that means we get the grade from our function 
   if($key==1){
     $grade = getGrade($val);
   }
   if($key==2){
    // If key is 2 that means we need to echo the $grade
    echo $grade;
   } else {
    // else we just echo the array value
    echo $val;
   }
  echo "</td>";
 }
   // Finish table row
   echo "</tr>";
   }
 }

// End table
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Much Much appreciated , the code is much complicated here as I am trying to learn self learning with the PHP. I really find it hard to trace the code , however I deeply appreciate your efforts spent in helping me sir.

Answer (score 0):

Simple and easy ;)

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<?php
$data = array(
    array('Course', 'Mark', 'Grade'),
    array('OS', 90, ''),
    array('MIS', 85, ''),
    array('WD', 99, ''),
    array('OOP', 67, ''),
    array('DS', 70, ''),
    array('Prog', 80, ''),
    array('Prog', 50, ''),
    array('Prog', 40, ''),
    array('Prog', 30, ''),
    array('Prog', 20, ''),
    array('Prog', 10, ''),
    array('Prog', 0, '')
);

$grade_chars = array('E', 6 => 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A');

echo "<table border='2px black solid'>";
foreach($data as $row) {
    echo "<tr>";

    if($row[2] == '') {
        $val = (int)($row[1] / 10);
        $row[2] = $grade_chars[$val > 5 ? $val : 0];
    }

    foreach($row as $col) {
        echo "<td>" . $col . '</td>';
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Amazing and simple , I could easily understand how it worked here but Can I ask you why the if($row[2] == '') {
        $row[2] = $grade_chars[(int)($row[1] / 10)];  was  divided over ten ? and If I am not in need for the rest of the letter other than A B C D , It returns for me an error                      Notice: Undefined offset: 9 in C:\xampp\htdocs\aa.php on line 23

Comment: `why the if($row[2] == '') { $row[2] = $grade_chars[(int)($row[1] / 10)]; was divided over ten` Because the if statement prepares the row before it is send into the foreach. | I just updated the answer ;)